# Nintex workflow - Get document data of each item in document library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-on-prem, nintex

In my SharePoint site I need a workflow that gets the file data of each document in a library. Now I have a site workflow which queries on a certain libary and then loops through a foreach. In the loop I'm updating the properties of each item.

Here I want to fetch the file content. In an item workflow I can use **[FileData]** to get a base64 string with the document data.

Searching on this, some suggestions were the Read document action (which I don't have in the Nintex Workflow) or to do a web request (https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-Office-365/Get-document-from-Document-library-as-Base64/m-p/75264). This should return the binary stream of the document.

This is the request I executed:

```
https://SharePointUrl/_api/web/lists('list guid')/Files('*document name*')/$value
```

And this is the result I get:

```
    Response status code: 200

    Response content:
          PK
```

Does anyone has an idea how to get the binary stream of the document, which I later will use to convert to a base64?

Comment: What are your plans for the files?

Comment: @Billy I want to send the queried documents via DocuSign to get some signatures

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
https://SharePointUrl/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/docunentLibrary/panda.jpg')/openbinarystream
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Same response.